# Select not more than

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this minor problem.

I want to select something from the database, where the number is not more than a set number.

This is what i have (snippet):

```
$Level = "1"; //Retrieved from the DB, just keeping it simple.
@$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users,store WHERE users.ID = '$ID' AND store.LevelReq <='users.Level'");
```

The problem with this, it doesn't display anything that equals $level.

(Item ... Level: 0) - Displays
(Item ... Level: 1) - Doesn't display.

So what i'd like is the equivalent of php's !>1 (not more than 1) but in MYSQL format if possible, however this doesn't work.

Comment: It seems you don't use `$Level` anywhere in the MySQL query.

Comment: Did you mean to write?: `... AND store.LevelReq <= '$Level'"); `

Comment: [There is no `!>` operator in PHP.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: ypercube, yes i did. It works now, thank you ypercube and Tomalak.

Comment: @Anon2011: You don't need to spam every single answer here. Just mark the answer that solved your problem as _accepted_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember that 'not more than' is always the same as **'lower than and equal to'**, so you should use `field <= value`. (So in your case: `field <= 1`.)

Comment: That's what i am or was using (AND store.LevelReq <='users.Level'");) however, it's not displaying at all now.

Comment: If you are refering to another table inside the same query (so `othertable.field`) you have to omit the quotes, else MySQL will treat it as a *string*.

Comment: .. or do them properly: `\`users\`.\`Level\``.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that Level is a field of the table users, if it is true, then you have a quote problem in you query, and query with the PHP var, try:

```
$Query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users,store WHERE users.ID = '{$ID}' AND store.LevelReq <= {$Level}");
```

Comment: Yes that's true, and it was a problem with myself (as usual lol). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

tables and columns are escaped separately, therefor, instead of 'users.Level', try user.'level'. (table.column)

```
$Level = "1"; //Retrieved from the DB, just keeping it simple.
@$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users,store WHERE users.ID = '$ID' AND store.LevelReq <= users.'Level'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing store.LevelReq to the string "users.Level", not the column users.Level. Remove the quotes around users.Level, and everything should be well!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you shouldn't use backticks instead of single quotes? Like this:

```
$Level = "1"; //Retrieved from the DB, just keeping it simple.
@$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users,store WHERE users.ID = '$ID' AND store.LevelReq <=`users`.`Level`");
```

Comment: Did you mean `\`users\`.\`Level\``?

Comment: @Tomalak: Isn't it like that?

Comment: @Simon: Where do you see `Level` being a table?

Comment: @Shef: You wrote `\`users.Level\`` before, and you know it.

Comment: @Tomalak: Changed within seconds, and you know it! ;)

Comment: @Shef: After I posted my comment.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sure, I copied from you/used your suggestion, happier? :D